# Why won't my server start running?

Tags: python, django

Why am I getting an error when trying to run my server to access the database to see if my code works?  While in my projects folder in `Terminal`, I ran `sudo python manage.py runserver` to try to run the server but it doesn't work because of the aforementioned error.  I've looked around SO but can't find one directly related to my problem.

I'm guessing my `if()` statement is the problem.

The error I'm getting says:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from .models import Album
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import UserForm

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_albums'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/detail.html'

class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:index')

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'music/registration_form.html'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            #cleaned normalized data

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

Here's the `error`:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 255, in check
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 172, in check
    warnings = self._check_pattern_startswith_slash()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 140, in _check_pattern_startswith_slash
    regex_pattern = self.regex.pattern
```

Here's my `forms.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm): # UserForm inherits from forms.
    passwords = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta: # Information about your class.
        model = User # whenevr a creates sign up to your site it's gonna go in same table
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

Here's my `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/', include('music.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here's my `album_form.html` file:

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Add a New Album{% endblock %}
{% block album_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'music/form-template.html' %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sum-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{%  endblock %}
```

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
{# loads path to static file #}

{% extends 'music/base.html' %}

{% block body %}

    <ul>
        {% for album in all_albums %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.pk %}">{{ album.album_title }}</a></li>
        {%  endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @maSTAShuFu What's a CTE?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I put that tag by mistake.  Apologies for that.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a recursive reference from your include in music.urls to urls.py since the error that django throws is specific to URL resolver.

Your if statement has no error. 'music:index' refers to namespaced url names and still need named url statements in urls.py. Since in simple projects, there is only one application, the namespace is redundant. So in most cases, 'index' should be used instead, just like what I have show below.

In your urls.py, there is a include to music.urls, and it seems to be recursive reference to itself. 'music.urls' refers to the file urls.py in music directory. 
If you do not have a valid python object for 'music.urls', then your include statement is wrong.

I do not use include urls in my project, so there will need to be a statement for each view defined in views.py. To test whether your server starts correctly, I would try the following urlpatterns. Don't forget to import IndexView and DetailView. Add more url statements for you other views after testing out 1 or 2 first.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^music/index/$', IndexView.as_view() , name='Index'),
    url(r'^music/detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DetailView.as_view() , name='Detail'),
]
```

I use named url, and the  statement in index.html should be written as follows:

```
<a href="{% url 'Detail' album.pk %}">{{ album.album_title }}</a>
```

The namespace 'music:' is omitted since it is implicit and will look simpler. You should leave it out for simple applications as it may be confusing for beginners.

Comment: I don't have a music.urls file.  I only have a urls.py file

Comment: I have a for loop in my `album_form.html`  file that of which I just posted, maybe that's what's causing it?